# What is the best way for the view model to use the view's dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dispatcher, formatted-text

The following code is in the View Model:

I am creating a display list using FormattedText. I need to obtain the final metrics of what the display will be prior to leaving the method that created the formatted text (i.e., prior to the normal mechanism of rendering when the method completes). I have been trying something along these lines using the dispatcher, but cannot seem to obtain the final meterics. The actual formattedtext, ft, of the StringViewModel is always null regardless of how I set up the dispatcher or how it is invoked. I am gathering that the action is being performed prior to the dispatcher doing the rendering.  (Net 4.0)

```
 Action<StringViewModel> action = delegate(StringViewModel sv)
                    {
                        // do stuff to UI, e.g.
                        var Height = sv.ft.Height;
                    };

                    svm.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, action, svm);
```

Any help please. How can this be done? Any idea would be great!

StringViewModel:

```
public class StringViewModel : FrameworkElement
{

    public StringViewModel(
        Point topleft, 
        string text, 
        double fontsizediu, 
        SolidColorBrush brush, 
        Func<FormattedText,FormattedText> f,        
        double lineheight)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.emSize = fontsizediu;                
        this.color = brush;
        this.topleft = topleft;
        this.lineheight = lineheight;               
        this.f = f;
    }


    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {

        ft = new FormattedText(
            text, 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(new FontFamily("Segoe Script"), FontStyles.Italic, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal),
            emSize, 
            color);

        ft.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        if (lineheight == null)
                    ft.LineHeight = 1.25 * FontSize;        

        ft = f(ft);

        dc.DrawText(ft, topleft);

    }
```

Edit:

All the above code is in the View Model, not the code behind, if I change this to

```
  StringViewModel svm = new StringViewModel(p, r, FontSizeDIU, b, stringstyle, LineHeight);
                    Strings.Add(svm);

                    this.theView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                             DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(Object state)
                                {
                                    var size = svm.DesiredSize;
                                    return null;
                                }
                            ), null);
```

where ObservableCollection Strings and theView is a reference to the view, all WORKS CORRECTLY.

So, what is the recommended way of not having the view model "know" of the view and yet use the view's dispatcher to measure the rendered text?

Comment: when using MVVM you may need perhaps need to identify why you need to use the dispatcher in a viewmodel anyway?

Comment: @pushpraj It seems the easiest way to obtain the exact metrics of FormattedText. If there is a better way, please tell me.